# How to PHP Export Serialized Data to Excel

Tags: php

is there any other way to extract serialized data from sql to excel? I tried to do this

```
    <?php
$hostname_dbconnect = "localhost";
$database_dbconnect = "upload_dodwnload";
$username_dbconnect = "root";
$password_dbconnect = "";
$dbconnect = mysql_pconnect($hostname_dbconnect, $username_dbconnect, $password_dbconnect) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_emp_sched";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("no query");
$row_try=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($result);

/*
$empid=unserialize($row_try['Employee_ID']);
$empname=unserialize($row_try['Emp_FullName']);
$empwrk=unserialize($row_try['Emp_WrkFrcCode']);
$empsch=unserialize($row_try['Emp_SchdCode']);

$datas= array(
            "0" => $empid,
            "1" => $empname,
            "2" => $empwrk,
            "3" => $empsch
            );

print_r ($datas);
*/

$array_try = array($result['Employee_ID'],$result['Emp_FullName'],$result['Emp_WrkFrcCode'],$result['Emp_SchdCode']);
while($datas = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $array_try[] = $datas;

}

  function cleanData(&$str)
  {
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
  }

  $filename = "Rota_Schedule_(Schedule Codes)" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";

  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

  $flag = false;
  foreach($array_try as $datas) {
    if(!$flag) {
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($datas)) . "\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($datas, 'cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($datas)) . "\n";
  }


?>
```

but i don't get what i want. Anybody can help me? This problem causing me hours and hours of testing, any other idea? I tried to unserialize it first but the code just gone crazy and not working properly. Anybody can help me? Thanks

Comment: Please provide the exact error or unintended output you're receiving.

Comment: [UNEXPECTEDOUTPUT](http://imgur.com/qQwjqnv) This is the unexpected output. I need the export thing to be unserialized but the output was serialize

Comment: any one can help me out here? I'm so tired. No one helps me here in the office because they don't know how to code in php even me. Oh god. :(